# Google calendar API : Description from event has unexpected characters

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I get unexpected characters in my description. It's strange because it look like HTML entities but a function like `html_entities_decode()` wont work with `amp;` or `nbsp;`.

You can see the result I get from my Event below.

**Picture result Get Event From Google Calendar API**

[image: Picture result Get Event From Google Calendar API]

Comment: I tried to reproduce this with PHP code and directly from Calendar API and I couldn't. Could you provide the code you're using and the event description as it is shown in the Calendar UI?

Comment: @AndresDuarte I have a Google Calendar Class and a function getEvent :

`function getEvent($eventId)
{
        try {
            $event = $this->service->events->get($this->calurl, $eventId);
            if(!$event)return false;
            return $event;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            error_log('Google getEvent : '.$e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }`

Comment: Add the formatted code to the question please